# How to use fulltext matching for emails in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, innodb

I'm adding a "search by email" functionality on my contacts database table (MySQL, InnoDB engine) for our CRM system. I added the FULLTEXT index and partial searches like this

```
WHERE MATCH(cc.email_c) AGAINST('Joe' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

are working fine. However, if I try to match against a full email address like this

```
WHERE MATCH(cc.email_c) AGAINST('Joe@gmail.com' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

all email addresses with Gmail get returned. I've already discarded the possibility of using BOOLEAN MODE, from what I understand it doesn't support the "@" symbol in a query. Is there any other way of using a MATCH AGAINST while still being able to search by the exact full address?

I can always use an SQL with LIKE and some wildcards, but I would still prefer to have a full-text search.

Comment: Long story short: combine full text search with `LIKE`, using `OR`. If you want to know why read the documentation how fulltext search works in general.

Comment: @emix - Not `OR`.

Answer (score -1):

Convert it to `AGAINST('+Joe +gmail +com' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

But, beware; short names and "stop words" should not have a '+' on front of them.

Then, because it won't be precise enough, combine with a `LIKE`:

```
WHERE MATCH(email) AGAINST('+Joe +gmail +com' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND email LIKE '%Joe@gmail.com%'
```

The first part gives you speed; the second part will test only the ones that pass the first test.

Comment: Is there a flaw that led to the downvote?  Maybe I can fix it.